# project organization between x86 and x64

Tags: c#, c++, ide

I have a mixed language solution in VS2008. I would like to structure the bin such that I have

bin\x86\Release

and

bin\x64\Release

among the other options. I can do something like this if I have all C# or all C++, but as the platform names don't overlap (x86 vs. Win32) between C++ and C#, I can't seem to do this with the macros (and have an easy solution). I've tried to add a new platform and it won't let me. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No problem, just change the output folders for each configuration.  In the C++ IDE it is General + Output Directory, make it $(SolutionDir)x86\$(ConfigurationName) for Win32.  In the C# IDE it is Project + Properties, Build tab, Output path.

Switch between configurations and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using VS2008 Standard Edition? if yes, then you can configure your structure using the Batch Build option... Got to Build -> Batch Build and select the buiild settings that you wish...

Hope this helps...

Thanks,
Ram